# Creating a custom helper class in module

Tags: magento-1.7, module, helper

I've made a new module called `test_helper` and I want to create a helper class in this module so that I can add custom functions to be called all over my site.

I can't however seem to find any examples of just how to go about doing this. I assume I have to create some extra xml in config and ad another file somewhere that extends a base helper but I've not had any luck finding an example to build upon.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Your module naming convention is quite confusing - you're calling the module itself helper? For the purpose of explaining, I'm choosing to call your module `myname_mymodule`

In your module `./app/code/community/MyName/MyModule/etc/config.xml`, within the `<global>` tags

```
<helpers>
  <mymodule>
      <class>MyName_MyModule_Helper</class>
  </mymodule>
</helpers>
```

Then create the file `./app/code/community/MyName/MyModule/Helper/Data.php`

```
<?php

class MyName_MyModule_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract{

}
```

Then to call that module, you would use

```
$helper = Mage::helper('mymodule');
```

Answer (score 9):

Add a directory Helper in the extension directory and in there a file `Data.php`

```
class Test_Helper_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {

  public function yourFunction() {
     ...
     your code here
     ...
  } 

}
```

Now you can call it via

```
Mage::helper('test/helper')->yourFunction();
```

Also add the following in your `config.xml`

```
...
<global>
    ...
    <helpers>
        <[extension name]>
            <class>[Namespace]_[extension name]_Helper</class>
        </[extension name]>
    </helpers>
    ...
</global>
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much you two, This backs up the tiny bit of info I was able to find and I was able to get it working in the end. I'm not actually calling it test_helper that was just for me to go through stuff on my litle test block but yeah dumb idea calling it helper =p

Comment: You're probably better off renaming it but main thing is it works! good luck with the project