# Add php function to price of Products with Custom Options

Tags: php, price, template, html

I added a php function to magento price template this way

I added this code:

```
<?php
function Convert2farsi ($srting)
    {
      $search= array("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9");
      $replace= array("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J");
      $int= str_replace($search,$replace,$srting);
      return$int;
    }
?>
```

to `app/design/frontend/shopper/default/template/catalog/product/price.phtml`

and changed this line price.phtml:

```
<?php $_convertedPrice = $_store->roundPrice($_store->convertPrice($_product->getPrice())); ?>
```

to this:

```
<?php $_convertedPrice = $_store->roundPrice($_store->convertPrice(Convert2farsi ($_product->getPrice()))); ?>
```

Problems:

1. Products with Custom Options wont take effect of this code and are showing in their past way.
2. In each category just one product is shown and the others are missing.
3. Product prices won't show on category hover mode and give this error on hover: `cannot redeclare Convert2farsi () previously declared in .../price.phtml line 28 and 34`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `price.html` has a lot more lines where price is output. If it is too complicated for you, try the [price.phtml template without all the Weee stuff](https://gist.github.com/sandermangel/de408f7bbea33c8b7771)
2. I guess an error is stopping further output.
3. The best way is to to create a helper with function `Convert2farsi` - [creating a helper](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/magento-1-7-creating-a-custom-helper-class-module). But if you won't, you should check if function was declared to avoid redeclaration:

   ```
   if (!function_exists('Convert2farsi')) {
       function Convert2farsi ($srting) {
           //...
       }
   }
   ```